# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Tags: php, arrays, string

How can i fix this? i want make this :

```
$diagnosa=blabla , blabla2 , blabla3 , ;
```

and then i use foreach but it cannot work,

```
$nama_diagnosa = Laporan::ViewDataDiagnosa(2,'2015-02-02');
$diagnosa = foreach ($nama_diagnosa as $cellDiagnosa){
    echo $cellDiagnosa['nama_diagnosa']." , ";
 }
```

Comment: Use [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode).

Comment: so, how can i fix it?

Comment: Is the first line meant to be an array? At the moment this would just produce a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[resolved]
Finally I added temporary variables to hold data for diagnosatemp variable, then I add a diagnosa variable like this

```
$nama_diagnosa=Laporan::ViewDataDiagnosa($cell['id_pasien'],$cell['tgl_rekam']);
                $diagnosa = '';
                foreach ($nama_diagnosa as $cellDiagnosa){
                    $diagnosaTemp=$cellDiagnosa['nama_diagnosa'];
                    $diagnosa=$diagnosa.",".$diagnosaTemp;
                } echo $diagnosa;
```